# "Call to a member function store() on array" When Uploading a File using Laravel 8 with Jetstream - Vue & Intertia.js

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios, inertiajs

I am having a problem uploading an image from a from a form in a vue file. I tried several ways to do this but it seems the file is not properly being set.

- I have set "enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form tag
- Here is my input element:

  <input
  @change="onFileChange"
  type="file"
  accept="image/*"
  class="form-control"
  name="file"
  id="file"
  aria-describedby="helpId"
  placeholder="Upload a file"
  />
- Here is my data objetcs and methods that send the data:

  ```
    data() {
        return {
      editMode: false,
      professionaldevelopmentitems: [],
      professionaldevelopmentitem: {
        domain: 1,
        domaincategory: 1,
        title: "",
        dateofpd: "",
        location: "",
        lengthofpd: "",
        facilitatorname: "",
        facilitatorcredentials: "",
        reflection: "",
        file: "",
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChange(e) {
      alert(e.target.files[0]);
      alert(e.target.files[0].name);
      var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length)
        return;
      this.professionaldevelopmentitem.file = e.target.files[0];
      alert(this.professionaldevelopmentitem.file);
    },    
    async addProfessionalDevelopmentItem() {
      document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
      this.editMode = false;
      const res = await axios.post(
        "/api/professionaldevelopmentitems",
        this.professionaldevelopmentitem
      );

      if (res.status === 201) {
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: res.data,
        });
        document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
        $("#manageProfessionalDevelopmentItem").modal("hide");
        Fire.$emit("modifiedPDItem");
      }
    },
    async editProfessionalDevelopmentItem(data) {
      this.professionaldevelopmentitem = Object.assign({}, data);
      this.editMode = true;
    },
    async updateProfessionalDevelopmentItems(data) {
      const res = await axios.put(
        `/api/professionaldevelopmentitems/${data.id}`,
        this.professionaldevelopmentitem
      );

      if (res.status === 200) {
        Toast.fire({
          icon: "success",
          title: res.data,
        });
        document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
        $("#manageProfessionalDevelopmentItem").modal("hide");
        Fire.$emit("modifiedPDItem");
        this.editMode = false;
      }
    },
  ```

I receive data in my controller and try to store the file:

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

```
dd($request->all());

$this->validate($request, [
    'title' => ['required'],
    'dateofpd' => ['required'],
    'lengthofpd' => ['required'],
    'location' => ['required']
]);

$path = $request->file('filename')->store('uploads');

$pditem = ProfessionalDevelopmentItem::find($id);
$pditem->domain = $request->domain;
$pditem->domaincategory = $request->domaincategory;
$pditem->title = $request->title;
$pditem->dateofpd = $request->dateofpd;
$pditem->lengthofpd = $request->lengthofpd;
$pditem->location = $request->location;
$pditem->facilitatorname = $request->facilitatorname;
$pditem->facilitatorcredentials = $request->facilitatorcredentials;
$pditem->certificategranted = $request->certificategranted;
$pditem->certificateexpires = $request->certificateexpires;
$pditem->certificateexpiration = $request->certificateexpiration;
$pditem->reflection = $request->reflection;
$pditem->nameofinstitution = $request->nameofinstitution;
$pditem->coursename = $request->coursename;
$pditem->coursecode = $request->coursecode;
$pditem->hoursofinstruction = $request->hoursofinstruction;
$pditem->creditgranted = $request->creditgranted;
$pditem->bookname = $request->bookname;
$pditem->bookauthor = $request->bookauthor;
$pditem->bookyear = $request->bookyear;
$pditem->bookpublisher = $request->bookpublisher;
$pditem->otherdescription = $request->otherdescription;
$pditem->filename = $path;

$pditem->save();

return response('Successfully Updated the Professional Development Item.', 200);
```

}

the response back is an error on the line when it tries to store the file:

```
"message": "Call to a member function store() on array",
"exception": "Error",
```

Any thoughts on what I am dong wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$path = $request->file('filename')->store('uploads');`

Comment: Thanks, I just added that - it did not make a difference.

Comment: try to check whats inside `$request->file('filename')` using `dd($request->file('filename'));`

Comment: null is dumped with that. FYI the last alert "alert(this.professionaldevelopmentitem.file);" shows "[object File]" so it seems like professionaldevelopmentitem.file is being set with the file, but it seems it's not coming across then for some reason

Comment: If I run this: "dd($request->file);" the response is "[]".

Comment: you are running the wrong dd, either try to run the whole request using `dd($request)` or use `$request->file('filename')`, also check `dd($request->hasFile('filename'))` returns true of false

Comment: Ok thanks.  `dd($request->hasFile('filename'))` returns false

Comment: I think based on your Vue component code the file should be available under "file" key. Try `dd($request->hasFile('file'))`

Comment: `dd($request->hasFile('file'))` also returns false

Comment: Check with `dd($request->all())` and see what keys are there

Comment: Both `"filename" => null` and `"file" => []` are there. "Filename" is the column name that I am trying to update with the path further down in the update function - I updated the question with the full update function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sending the uploaded file within FormData. Define a method in the Vue component to prepare the FormData with all data you want to send via ajax to the server

```js
prepareFormData() {
    let data = new FormData;

    Object.keys(this.professionaldevelopmentitem).forEach(
        key => data.append(key, this.professionaldevelopmentitem[key]
    );

    return data;
}
```

Then use this method to get the FormData and send it as data to the server in `addProfessionalDeveloomentItem` and `updataProfessionalDevelopmentItems`

```js
async addProfessionalDevelopmentItem() {
    document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
    this.editMode = false;
    const res = await axios.post(
      "/api/professionaldevelopmentitems",
      this.prepareFormData()
    );

    if (res.status === 201) {
      Toast.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: res.data,
      });
      document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
      $("#manageProfessionalDevelopmentItem").modal("hide");
      Fire.$emit("modifiedPDItem");
    }
  },
  

  async updateProfessionalDevelopmentItems(data) {
    const res = await axios.put(
      `/api/professionaldevelopmentitems/${data.id}`,
      this.prepareFormData()
    );

    if (res.status === 200) {
      Toast.fire({
        icon: "success",
        title: res.data,
      });
      document.getElementById("pdForm").reset();
      $("#manageProfessionalDevelopmentItem").modal("hide");
      Fire.$emit("modifiedPDItem");
      this.editMode = false;
    }
}
```

Then you should get the uploaded file in the $request under key file $request->file('file')

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `$request->file('filename')` returns array. In our case  it's because we allowed users to submit 2 files at once:

```
<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="filename[]"><br>
    <input type="file" name="filename[]"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To fix this in Laravel 9 we added the type check of the variable in the controller's method:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('filename');

    if (is_array($file)) {
        foreach ($file as $item) {
            $item->store('uploads');
        }
    } else {
        $file->store('uploads');
    }

    // ...
}
```